# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in ubntu

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, database-connection

I am getting exception `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` . In my Spring boot application .Here is my `application.properties` file looks like.

```
  spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test? 
  verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false
  spring.datasource.username=root
  spring.datasource.password=root@123
  spring.datasource.initialize=true
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
  spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Whenever i am trying to login with `MySql` using terminal `mysql -u root -p` i am getting same error on terminal too . But once i used `sudo` before `mysql` it does connect with same password `root@123`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've not set the password for mysql correctly. To get on with your task you can update the password for the root user in the mysql.
To update password:

1. Stop the MySQL Server: sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop.
2. Start the mysqld configuration: sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
3. Login to MySQL as root: mysql -u root mysql
4. Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password:

   UPDATE
     mysql.user
   SET
     Password = PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD')
   WHERE
     User = 'root';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   exit;

Answer (score -1):

root@123 != root@localhost.
try to create a user 'root'@'localhost' in my sql.
https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/reset-mysql-root-password
and grant him access : https://kyup.com/tutorials/create-new-user-grant-permissions-mysql/